# cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) vs cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])

Tags: python, opencv

There are these two options to turn a single channel image into a 3 channel image:

`cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` vs `cv2.merge([gray, gray, gray])`

What's the implementation differences? Which one is faster?

Comment: Which particular implementation do you have in mind? For `cvtColor` there are at least 4 I'm aware of -- plain, SIMD, OCL, IPP. | `cvtColor` will have an advantage in that it only needs to read each gray pixel once, whereas `merge`  would need to read from each of the 3 input arrays (even though they are all the same thing).

Comment: Which question do you want answered? Questions on Stack Overflow should ask one question, not multiple.

Comment: I'm not aware of what implementation I have. `pip list`: `opencv-python 4.3`, this?

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to give consistent results that `cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` is faster than `cv2.merge([gray, gray, gray])`

Given that cvtColor COLOR_BGR2GRAY is also arguably more legible/explicit in its function and we have a clear winner.

`cvtColor` should be used over `merge`

```
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np

image = (np.random.standard_normal([20000, 20000, 3]) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


start = time.time()
gray_BGR = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
print("cvtColor COLOR_GRAY2BGR took", time.time() - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
gray_three = cv2.merge([gray, gray, gray])
print("merge took", time.time() - start, "seconds")
```